# Android fragment is not loading

Tags: android-fragments

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.diveshpanwar.gossip31.MyFragment1' , required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
```

This pops up when I write

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,myFragment1)
```

Help please

Comment: I have already included that, but the fragment class i have created is in com.example. diveshpanwar... while the fragmentTransaction.replace is trying to replace the base class in android.support

Answer (score 0):

The android.support.v4.app.Fragment is the class that you need for targeting pre-API 11 devices.  Looks like maybe you just forgot to include that library.